# replacing text in Swiffy

Tags: google-swiffy

I have a Swiffy file and can see the text converted from Flash in the swiffyobject. 
Tried to simply replace the text with new text, but the old text still displays in the movie. 
Is text replacement even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, easily, but the results can be problematic.

First, are you viewing your file off a test server? - maybe it's a cache issue. On a local swiffy file, I had no problem changing a word (from "dawn" to "sunset"). But the letter spacing went haywire, and the "t" went missing. It looks like swiffy assigns an x-y position and height to each piece of text, so you can only reliably replace text with text of the exact same length.